# Getting user email using Twitter API

Tags: php, api, twitter

I'm trying to get user email using twitter API.
My App is in whitelist and I received response about user using users/show.json without any problems:
Request URL:

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?oauth_consumer_key=xxx&oauth_nonce=xxx&oauth_signature=xx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1466232185&oauth_token=xxx&oauth_version=1.0&screen_name=xxx

But when I'm trying to use `verify_credentials.json` with `include_email=true` I'm getting this error:

> HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 401 Authorization Required

Request URL (almost the same as above):

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/verify_credentials.json?oauth_consumer_key=xxx&oauth_nonce=xxx&oauth_signature=xx&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1466232185&oauth_token=xxx&oauth_version=1.0&include_email=true

As described here in the [twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials)
I'm getting `401 error` if authentication was unsuccessful. But why when I'm accessing `show.json` I'm getting successfull response and when I'm trying to acccess `verify_credentials` I'm getting `401` error?

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Got it working with twitteroauth library.

Answer (score 0):

1. did you white list your app?

not all apps are able to fetch the user's email but only the ones which already been white listed by twitter. 
if not go to your app in apps.twitter.com and authorize it

2. did you use the authorize edge on the user again?

after activating the email fetch in apps.twitter.com you need to reauthorize the user to be able to fetch the email from him.